# How to create dynamic horizontal table row in android?

Tags: java, android

My current code is:

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String b = json_data.getString("examnames");
            JSONObject getexamnamesobject = new JSONObject(b);
            getexamnames=getexamnamesobject.getString("types");
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            createView(tr,tv1,getexamnames);
            t1.addView(tr);
        }
public void createView(TableRow tr, TextView t, String viewdata) {
        t.setText(viewdata);
        //adjust the porperties of the textView
        t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //t.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        //t.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        t.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0); 
        tr.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 1); 
        //tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        tr.addView(t); // add TextView to row.
        }
```

My output for above code is, I'm getting textviews vertically like this:

```
English
Maths
Science
```

What must be the change in the above coding to get the horizontal output like this:

```
English Maths Science
```

Please help me. This very important for me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set setStretchAllColumns(*) and setShrinkAllColumns(*) to the table layout. and make it orientation "horizontal" for the table layout.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a TableRow and adding it to your TableLayout once for each item in jArray.  Your createView method adds one string to that row: the value for the "types" key on the json object from the corresponding item in jArray (`getexamnamesobject.getString("types")`).

You might have to just loop through and collect all the "types" strings with a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and put them in a single TableRow.

Comment: can you please help me with a code.(I'm a newbie to java & android). And aren't there any other methods provided by android for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your new LayoutParams should be new TableRow.LayoutParams. Views with "naked" LayoutParams could not be stacked one after another.